# How do I inject the ApplicationContext to a non-activity class using Dagger2?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-application-class

I have several classes that I would like to inject to. For example, I have an *APIContentLoader* class I use for downloading JSON from an endpoint and then storing it to the database. I would like to inject the *DatabaseManager* class I made for reading/writing to the database into *APIContentLoader*. In order to inject the *DatabaseManager* into this class, I first need a reference to the *ApplicationContext*, correct?

This is how I have it setup right now:

```
public class APIContentLoader{
    @Inject DatabaseManager dbm;
    @Inject BaseApplication app;

    public APIContentLoader(){
        app.getAppComponent().inject(this);
        // dbm now is ready for use
    }  
    ... // rest of class stuff
}
```

My *BaseApplication* class extends the standard Application class. Is injecting the *BaseApplication* reference to this class in this manner bad practice? I know making a static reference to the ApplicationContext is not a good way to go about making it available to these non-activity classes.

I guess the big question is, does this approach present the same problems of a static reference as far memory management and persisting the lifespan of these helper classes?

Comment: Does `APIContentLoader` really just extend `Object` as shown here, or is it actually a `Loader`?

Comment: Also: "I know making a static reference to the application context is not a good way to go about making it available . . ." I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Its just an object. I think i need to get a better understanding for dependency injection before I try to implement it much further. I was shooting for an MVP structure and to be able to inject all my helper classes for downloading/storing data into the presenters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I'm getting at with my question about what your class actually is:

Android components (activities, services, etc.) benefit from dependency injection because they require a no-arg constructor so the framework can create instances of them.  A class that's not instantiated by the Android framework should simply receive its dependencies as constructor arguments.  There's no reason to have `@Inject` fields in such a class.